# Bluetooth dongle drivers

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I hope you can help me... I bought a bluetooth dongle ([Logilink BT0054](https://www.2direct.de/en/audio-video/bluetooth-wireless-adapters/4574/bluetooth-5.0-adapter-usb-3.2-usb-a-and-usb-c?number=BT0054)), and did want to get it working on linux. Whenever I plug it in, these messages appear in `dmesg`:

```
[ 6185.169440] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 6185.417009] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8771
[ 6185.417012] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6185.417013] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[ 6185.417014] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 6185.417015] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00E04C239987
[ 6185.431031] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[ 6185.431034] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
[ 6185.431050] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin failed with error -2
[ 6185.431052] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
[ 6185.434008] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 6185.434013] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 0, total size 20204
[ 6187.921147] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[ 6195.921559] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
```

relevant output of `usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  9 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8771 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio
S:  SerialNumber=00E04C239987
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

I searched for solutions, and the best hit I found was [this forum post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=319260) - although the chipset (idVendor & idProduct) seems to match with my hardware, I am quite unsure if those drivers are useable for me (since my dongle is manufactured from a complete different company).

This forum post mentions a kernel patch which seems to be necessary, which (from what they write) is only present in the mainstream kernel 5.8 - since I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, my kernel version is 4.15.0-136 . Does anybody have experience with this, and is able to give some advice what is necessary to get it working?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643707/465237

Answer (score 2):

After some further hours of researching, I got it working. For anyone wondering how everything is put together, here is what I found out:
[This](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/bluetooth/patch/20200410145420.108868-2-sztsian@gmail.com/) kernel patch is not (yet) available inside the Ubuntu-4.15 kernel. It patches the Bluetooth-USB module responsible for loading the correct firmware, because the current module identifies the chipset as rtl8761a, even though it is revision b... This leads to loading the wrong firmware.

Now, anyone wanting to get this working has two options:

- install a kernel with modules which has the linked patch applied
- replace the kernel module btusb.ko by a different one

The linked drivers (from MPOW) work by implementing the second step - they rename the original module `btusb.ko` to `btusb_bak`, and install their own module instead. The new module identifies the chip correct, and searches for the correct firmware.

Once I copied `rtl8761bu_config` and `rtl8761bu_fw` to `/lib/firmware`, my bluetooth dongle worked like a charm.

Comment: I have exactly the same product and I use ubuntu. Can you help me to work it correctly? I downloaded the drivers but they are for windows. How did you install them then?

Comment: You need the drivers for linux. Go to the mpow download page ( https://www.xmpow.com/pages/download ), click on "USB Adapters" -> "Drivers", choose a USB adapter, and download the linux drivers...

Comment: How can i find what chipset i have on bluetooth Logilink BT0054? Bluetooth USB Adapter BH519, BH456A and BH079A presents the page! What i must download?

Comment: read the linked forum post; as far as I know, the Logilink BT0054 has the chipset rtl8761bu. The forum post suggests to download the drivers for MPOW BH456A; I downloaded the driver for BH519, it seems to work either way.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE 1: You need "Bluetooth USB" instructions, NOT "Bluetooth Device" instructions. HCI tools (as I read) are useful for hardware devices e.g. motherboards, cards, etc. -- not for USB devices.

NOTE 2: 1min. and 20 seconds to transfer a single image file (~7mb).

- Faster way to transfer files wirelessly from Android to Linux Desktop / PC (and much more) is by using KDE connect
- In some seconds, I transferred 50mbs to my Linux desktop.

> [kdeconnect wireless transfer files between andoid and linux desktop](https://www.howtogeek.com/423442/how-to-wirelessly-transfer-android-files-to-a-linux-desktop/)

I had also bought a Logilink BT0054. It didn't work. What I did with the help of @Martin :

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/bluetooth`
- `sudo apt install bluetooth blueman bluez bluez-tools rfkill libbluetooth-dev`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo apt install btrtl-rtl8723de-dkms`

Then...

- Go to [xmpow.com/pages/download](https://www.xmpow.com/pages/download) as suggested by Martin
- Click on "USB Adapters" -> "Drivers", choose a USB adapter, and download the Linux drivers as suggested by Martin  (I chose one at random)
- Unzip content at Download folder
- Find a folder named something like this "20200610_LINUX_BT_DRIVER"
- `cd ~/20200610_LINUX_BT_DRIVER` and `sudo make install INTERFACE=usb`

Then...

- Restart
- Make again - `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo modprobe rtk_btusb && dmesg | grep rtk`
- Run bluetooth manager.
- Make it "permanent visible" in Adapter menu, if you like, for easier detection.
- Caution! Don't forget when opening your Bluetooth that hackers may exist!

Useful commands for detection of bluetooth:

- `sudo modprobe btusb` "not found" appears to me while bluetooth works
- `lsmod | grep bluetooth`

> ```
> bluetooth             520192  41 hci_uart,bnep,rtk_btusb,rfcomm
> ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
> ```

- `modinfo rtk_btusb`

> ```
> filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-144-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/rtk_btusb.ko
> license:        GPL
> version:        3.1.897f3bb.20201202-173003
> description:    Realtek Bluetooth USB driver ver 3.1.897f3bb.20201202-173003
> author:         
> srcversion:     3522FC1E4EC17E8C6EC22B3
> alias:          usb:v1358p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
> alias:          usb:v0489p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
> alias:          usb:v13D3p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
> alias:          usb:v0BDAp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
> depends:        bluetooth
> retpoline:      Y
> name:           rtk_btusb
> vermagic:       4.15.0-144-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
> ```

- `lsusb`

> Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

- `uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth`

  ```
      Linux eliasc 4.15.0-144-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 8 02:33:43 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
      03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
          Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
          Kernel driver in use: r8169
          Kernel modules: r8169
      Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
      Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
      Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
      Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  ```

  .............

  ```
      Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      [    1.944846] usb 3-9: Product: Bluetooth Radio
      [   90.765641] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
      [   90.765653] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
      [   90.765655] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
      [   90.765656] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
      [   90.765659] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
      [   91.222481] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.2.74e8f89.20201202-173004
      [   91.222482] Bluetooth: HCI H4 protocol initialized
      [   91.222482] Bluetooth: HCI Realtek H5 protocol initialized
      [  100.773759] rtk_btusb: Realtek Bluetooth USB driver ver 3.1.897f3bb.20201202-173003
      [  128.036009] Modules linked in: kvm_intel(+) kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek
  ```

  .......

  ```
      [  142.968927] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
      [  142.968928] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
      [  142.968930] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
      [  189.741194] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
      [  189.741200] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
      [  189.741208] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
      [    0.024000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
      [    0.046260] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
      [  100.786121] rtk_btusb: load_firmware start
      [  101.062116] rtk_btusb: load_firmware: New gEVersion 1
      [  101.062125] rtk_btusb: load_firmware done
      [  145.113188] rtk_btusb: Firmware already exists
      bluetooth             520192  41 hci_uart,bnep,rtk_btusb,rfcomm
  ```

  - `sudo rfkill list`

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

- `sudo service bluetooth status`

> ```
> bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor 
>
> preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-07-02 09:36:12 EEST; 45min ago
>      Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
>
>  Main PID: 1283 (bluetoothd)
>    Status: "Running"
>     Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
>    CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
>            └─1283 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
>
> Jul 02 09:36:11 eliasc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
> Jul 02 09:36:11 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
> Jul 02 09:36:12 eliasc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
> Jul 02 09:36:12 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Starting SDP server
> Jul 02 09:36:14 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Bluetooth management interface 
>      1.14 initialized
> Jul 02 09:37:00 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Endpoint registered: 
>      sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
> Jul 02 09:37:00 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Endpoint registered: 
>      sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
> Jul 02 09:49:28 eliasc bluetoothd[1283]: Unable to get io data for Object 
>
> Push: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
> ```