# How to setup Bluetooth v5

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to get a Bluetooth 5 USB doogle working (MPOW BH456A). I've downloaded the latest version of the Linux driver from Mpow website and I've tried using the automated installation by running  `sudo make install INTERFACE=all`. This fails with the following errors:

```
rmmod btusb
mv /lib/modules/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb_bak
mv: cannot stat '/lib/modules/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko': No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:8: install] Error 1 (ignored)
rmmod rtk_btusb
rmmod: ERROR: Module rtk_btusb is not currently loaded
make: [Makefile:9: install] Error 1 (ignored)
make -C ./bluetooth_usb_driver
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jason/Desktop/mpow driver/20201202_LINUX_BT_DRIVER/usb/bluetooth_usb_driver'
make -C /lib/modules/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64/build M=/home/jason/Desktop/mpow driver/20201202_LINUX_BT_DRIVER/usb/bluetooth_usb_driver modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'driver/20201202_LINUX_BT_DRIVER/usb/bluetooth_usb_driver'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jason/Desktop/mpow driver/20201202_LINUX_BT_DRIVER/usb/bluetooth_usb_driver'
make: *** [Makefile:10: install] Error 2
```

I'm on the KDE spin of Fedora 32.

Output from `dmesg | grep bt`:

```
[    8.518603] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    8.526797] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
[    8.530001] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    8.530007] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin not found
[ 1044.227505] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
```

Output from `lsusb | grep -i blue`:

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

Output from `uname -r`:

```
5.10.22-100.fc32.x86_64
```

Here are the instruction for manual installation of the bluetooth drivers from MPOW which I'm trying to follow:

```
-Installation

  1. Build and install USB driver, change to the driver directory
   $ cd usb
   $ sudo make install

  2. Copy the right FW file and config file to the correct path.
   $ sudo cp rtkbt-firmware/lib/firmware/rtl8xxxxx_fw /lib/firmware/
   $ sudo cp rtkbt-firmware/lib/firmware/rtl8xxxxx_config /lib/firmware/

   NOTE: PLEASE REFER THE FORWARD SECTION OF FILENAME LIST TO CORRESPOND THE FW FILENAME AND THE CONFIG FILENAME WITH THE CHIP.
           
  3. Insert Realtek Bluetooth dongle
    Check LMP subversion by the following command
    $ hciconfig -a

    Now RTK chip can be recognized by the system and bluetooth function can be used.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll describe my solution for Ubuntu 20.04. I've managed to compile `MPOW BH456A` successfully using `sudo make install INTERFACE=all` but the device remained unrecognizable.

After some research, I've discovered this GitHub repository that explains it's just a missing firmware file, as described in your output `firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin not found`. To apply this patch, just execute:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/pedrovagner/fix-ubuntu-bluetooth-adapter
sh fix-ubuntu-bluetooth-adapter/project.sh fix
```